# Full dependency injection and testing object creations

Tags: testing, dependency-injection, dependencies, factory

I've recently come across a Google video related to the Guice framework that talks about the full dependency injections. I have been struggling to write testable code and my main problem was with objects being created inside a class that makes that class that much less testable.

The video mainly categorized all the classes into two:

1. Classes responsible for object creation logic (factories, etc.)
2. Classes responsible for using the injected objects (business logic)

Business logic classes become fully testable now (using class level JUnit tests) as I will be injecting in mocked objects. I'm very happy about that.

However I'm now left with couple questions I can't answer about testing the classes that create the objects.

1. What would you test?
2. How would you do it?

Comment: Maybe you should just add some integration tests.